# Determine the free space on a CD-RW using command line utilites

Tags: linux, rhel, diskspace, linux-disk-free, cd-burning

I'm using the `wodim` command in bash with the `-multi` flag to write to a CD-RW without having to blank the disc in between writes. After writing enough sessions to the disc, I have to blank the disc to recover some of the multi-session overhead space.

How can I determine how much space is left on the disc before attempting to write more data to it?

The `df` command shows 0 KB available (100% capacity) for my multi-session disc regardless of how much data is actually on it.

I'm using RHEL 7, and it's important that I avoid installing additional 3rd party utilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105511/determining-a-cd-rws-capacity

Comment: @n.m. That question is looking for total space, not available space so although similar, my question is *arguably* not a duplicate. I probably should ask a moderator move this to Unix StackExchange though.

Comment: You can use subtraction. Anyway, that site is arguably better fit for this question.